# Security Preferences: Open Anyway button gone

Tags: security, monterey

I'm developing a desktop app, so it's unsigned. When launched first time, it fails with access denied. I used to be able to click Open Anyway in the Security Preferences, but now that button is gone. How to allow unsigned apps to run on Monterey?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, same as ever - *right click* > open

Answer (score 1):

I think:

Go to the executable, right-click, and then choose `Open`.

`Open Anyway` and fiddling with the settings has been gone for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing the quarantine attribute on the executable:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ~/myapp
```

*Right-click, Open* wasn't an option for me, because I'm running the command from Terminal (via `make`).